# Linux Ubuntu clears user data on each reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have dev board (Freescale T2080rdb) with default Linux running on it from NOR.

When I want to create new or modify any existing files (e.g. touch /home/root/foo.txt) next time on new boot, everything is cleared or pushed back to default content.

Any idea why is this happening?

I guess I need to provide more info, but sincerely I don't know what to provide, since I'm kinda new to this field.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu or are you running it ("trying") from an installation disk (USB/DVD)?

Comment: Sounds like your filesystem is volatile because it is using ramfs or tmpfs.  Use the `mount` command to display the filesystem type of `/` and/or `/home`.